# Session Management in CDSSO

Tags: openam, opensso

Do the session management between openAM and protected application work's in CDSSO environment. Because I find that in CDSSO setup if I invalidate a session in openam side, it still remain active in application side.

Answer (score 1):

You either have to ensure that notification mode for the agent, protecting the app works, or use polling mode for the agent, but minimal polling mode is 1 minute. So users can access protected pages for another minute after you invalidated the session on OpenAM.

Also be aware what polling means which regard to number of requests to OpenAM infrastructure.

Comment: notification is happening for session, but I can see their is a continuous polling happening for namingservice, how can I stop such polling?"[25/Jan/2014:18:41:05 +0530] "GET /openam/namingservice HTTP/1.1" 200 17"